# R: Error Running Example Code for reduce() from purrr package

Tags: r, list, purrr, tidyverse

I'm looking to use reduce() to concatenate a variable number of columns from a data frame pairwise. It looked like reduce() would do the job, so I tried some of the example code and got this error. I'm using RStudio,
Version 1.0.136

```
> require(tidyverse)

> x <- list(c(0, 1), c(2, 3), c(4, 5))
> x %>% reduce(c)
# Error: `x` must be a vector (not a NULL) 
> sessionInfo()
# R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
# Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6

# locale:
# [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

# attached base packages:
# [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

# other attached packages:
# [1] dplyr_0.5.0     purrr_0.2.2     readr_1.0.0     tidyr_0.6.1     tibble_1.2      ggplot2_2.2.1  
# [7] tidyverse_1.1.1

# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 # [1] Rcpp_0.12.9      xml2_1.1.1       magrittr_1.5     hms_0.3          rvest_0.3.2      mnormt_1.5-5    
 # [7] munsell_0.4.3    colorspace_1.3-2 lattice_0.20-34  R6_2.2.0         httr_1.2.1       stringr_1.1.0   
# [13] plyr_1.8.4       tools_3.3.2      parallel_3.3.2   grid_3.3.2       broom_0.4.1      nlme_3.1-130    
# [19] gtable_0.2.0     psych_1.6.12     DBI_0.5-1        modelr_0.1.0     readxl_0.1.1     lazyeval_0.2.0  
# [25] assertthat_0.1   reshape2_1.4.2   haven_1.0.0      stringi_1.1.2    forcats_0.2.0    scales_0.4.1    
# [31] lubridate_1.6.0  jsonlite_1.2     foreign_0.8-67
```

P.S. This is my first question, so I tried to err on the side of too much info. Let me know if I need to provide different/more/less information.

Comment: Can't reproduce the error with the same package versions. But try using `Reduce` from `base`: `x %>% Reduce(c, .)`.

Comment: Thanks @Abdou! Odd you couldn't reproduce it. Maybe I should add the version of RStudio.

Comment: Do you by any chance have a variable named `c` in your namespace/environment? I just ran `c <- c(2,2,4,4)` in my console and ran your chained operation again and it threw the same error as yours. When I remove the newly created variable (`rm(c)`), it worked again. Perhaps that could be the issue?

Comment: Ah, that's it! Lol, novice mistake. Thanks again, @Abdou.

Comment: @John_W also note the differences between `reduce`  and `Reduce` in R. One is from base and the other from purrr. try ?Reduce and ?reduce

Answer (score 0):

As said in comments there was a variable named `c` that masked the function `c`.

Don't ever name anything `c`, except maybe list elements or column names.